# Where to put Automapper in WPF MVVM EF application

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, automapper

WPF Application using MVVM design
I'm using EF as my ORM exposed via a service layer to my front end.

Reading around everything I've read says I should implement automapper in the service layer, but I don't see how that makes sense here.
The ViewModel is the one I wish to differ from the data entities surely so I should do the mapping in the ViewModel?

Or should I be doing it twice (seems overkill) ie map the EF entities to DTOs for the Service to pass to the Front End which then converts them into the ViewModel objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with DTOs or Automapper in an MVVM client application in the first place.  Just use EF types as Model types, and build ViewModels that compose Model types together.

But I wouldn't be concerned at all about coupling between the ViewModel and and Model.  The ViewModel is *already* a later of indirection between the View and the Model/Service layer, and you're almost always deploying all the parts together.  It's generally acceptable for a ViewModel to include Model types directly.

But if you do want to put Automapper somewhere, it belongs between the EF types and the Model types, just like it would be if your Services layer was a REST service and you wanted to use DTOs instead of EF Entity types.  In that case you may want to change the REST service without redeploying the application, and so having DTOs allow you to make database/EF changes without changing the data that the client receives.

Comment: Thanks yes It felt overengineered. OK - so I strip that out, and I'm left with a DataService class that wraps the DbContext and implement IDataService. This is consumed by the ViewModels. Inside the DataService I'm doing a couple of explicit casts from DbSet to ObservableCollection. Does this sound reasonable approach?

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  In client apps the stakes for this stuff is pretty low.  If you are unhappy with it later, you can refactor.